# Ansible on SLES: zypper plugin not able to install PostgreSQL 14

Tags: ansible, suse, sles, zypper

I am trying my hand on Ansible after having a very nice training in it. Currently, my task is to create a playbook that sets up a PostgreSQL cluster (with Patroni and etcd).

However, while installing PostgreSQL should be a pretty easy task, doing it using the `zypper` plugin throws an error. First, the part of the playbook that should install PostgreSQL:

```
- name: Installation PostgreSQL 14 Latest ohne Recommendations
  become: true
  zypper:
    disable_recommends: true
    name:
      postgresql14-server
      postgresql14-contrib
      postgresql14-devel
    update_cache: true
  when: ansible_host in pgservers
```

The error message given is this:

```
fatal: [goeccdb22l]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/zypper", "--quiet", "--non-interactive", "--xmlout", "install", "--type", "package", "--auto-agree-with-licenses", "--no-recommends", "--", "+postgresql14-server postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-devel"], "msg": "No provider of '+postgresql14-server postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-devel' found.", "rc": 104, "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n<stream>\n<message type=\"error\">No provider of &apos;+postgresql14-server postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-devel&apos; found.</message>\n</stream>\n", "stdout_lines": ["<?xml version='1.0'?>", "<stream>", "<message type=\"error\">No provider of &apos;+postgresql14-server postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-devel&apos; found.</message>", "</stream>"]}
```

Let's extract the error message:

```
"msg": "No provider of '+postgresql14-server postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-devel' found."
```

I tried to replicate the problem using the shell on the target server. However, running the command seems to be able to install the packages:

```
ansible@goeccdb22l:~> sudo /usr/bin/zypper install --type package --auto-agree-with-licenses --no-recommends -- +postgresql14-server postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 12 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  libecpg6 libopenssl-1_1-devel libpq5 postgresql postgresql14 postgresql14-contrib postgresql14-devel postgresql14-server postgresql-contrib postgresql-devel postgresql-server zlib-devel

The following package needs additional customer contract to get support:
  postgresql14

12 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 8.0 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 35.4 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/v/...? shows all options] (y):
```

I've removed only the `--quiet` and `--non-interactive` options from the command, but kept all other given options.

The best idea I have is that the user/privilege escalation workings could be different from me logging in as the Ansible user to the target and just using `sudo` before the command.

**Edit 1:** I have developed an idea what the problem could be. As I mentioned above, when I tested the command, I removed two options: `--quiet` and `--non-interactive`. Testing the command with those two options gives the message:

```
The flag --quiet is not known.
```

However, using `man zypper`, I can clearly see that `--quiet` is a documented option:

```
   -q, --quiet
       Suppress normal output. Brief (esp. result notification) messages and error messages will still be printed, though. If used together with conflicting --verbose option, the --verbose option takes preference.
```

Now, my idea is that Ansible calls the command it documents in the return XML, but that because somehow `--quiet` is not understood it interprets that as nothing providing the requested package list. So that would leave two questions:

- Why is `--quiet` not understood, yet documented? Is that a problem of SLES vs. OpenSuse?
- How to work around that?

As the Ansible `zypper` module has no option to suppress the `--quiet` option I don't see any chance of working around it with parameters. The last option would be to split the `zypper` task into smaller `shell` tasks which I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the help of a knowledgeable sysadmin I was able to diagnose the problem.

The list of packages documented above was not in fact a list. As I missed the dashes in front of the packages, Ansible accepted the packages with the newlines and everything as `one package name` and tried to install it.

The solution is to change the packages into a list of packages by prefixing them with dashes/minus signs.

The problem with `--quiet` was that it is a positional argument, and I used the wrong position when testing it.